# Finding distance between CLLocationCoordinate2D points

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location

I know from documentation we can find distance between two `CLLocation` points using the function, `distanceFromLocation:`. But my problem is I dont have CLLocation data type with me, I have the CLLocationCoordinate2D points. So how can I find distance between two CLLocationCoordinate2D points. I have seen the post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896/distancefromlocation-calculate-distance-between-two-points) but not helpful for me.

Comment: Distance calculations are actually quite tricky. You should really have a second look at CLLocation.

Comment: do u have lat and long then create cllocation and then use CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];

Comment: Check this : [distanceFromLocation - Calculate distance between two points][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896/distancefromlocation-calculate-distance-between-two-points

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should create an object of CLLocation using,

```
- (id)initWithLatitude:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude
    longitude:(CLLocationDegrees)longitude;
```

Then, you should be able to calculate the distance using

```
[location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
```

Comment: With code CLLocationDistance distance = [aCLLocationA distanceFromLocation:aCLLocationB];
// distance is a double representing the distance in meters  (Source - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10432069/1364174)

Comment: No needs to create CLLocation for getting distance between points. Please look at my answer at the bottom

Answer (score 37):

**Swift 5:**

```
extension CLLocation {
    
    /// Get distance between two points
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - from: first point
    ///   - to: second point
    /// - Returns: the distance in meters
    class func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)
        return from.distance(from: to)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I think more like this:
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    // In meteres
    func distance(#to:CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude)
        return from.distanceFromLocation(to)
    }
}

Answer (score 33):

If it is ok for you to get distance in meters between points, then

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = <some value>
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2 = <some value>
…
MKMapPoint point1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate1);
MKMapPoint point2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate2);
CLLocationDistance distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(point1, point2);
```

will return the distance between two points. No needs to create `CLLocation` by given `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. This defines are available since iOS 4.0

Comment: Good, but needs MapKit to be linked. Using CLLocation and then distance doesn't need it.

Answer (score 25):

**Swift5:** combined above thoughts

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    //distance in meters, as explained in CLLoactionDistance definition
    func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let destination=CLLocation(latitude:from.latitude,longitude:from.longitude)
        return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude).distance(from: destination)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    let point1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(myLocation)
    let point2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(friendLocation)
    let distance = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(point1, point2)/1000
    let distanceStr = NSString(format: "%.3f", distance)
```

Simple version of Valleri's answer. Divide by 1000 to get KM followed by conversion to string.

Answer (score 2):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D+Distance.swift` for Swift 5.5 based on `MapKit`:

```swift
import MapKit

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    /// Returns the distance between two coordinates in meters.
    func distance(to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        MKMapPoint(self).distance(to: MKMapPoint(to))
    }

}
```

Version based on `CLLocation`:

```swift
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    /// Returns the distance between two coordinates in meters.
    func distance(to: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            .distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: to.latitude, longitude: to.longitude))
    }

}
```

Both extensions have a performance overhead which might be relevant if processing a large amount of coordinates. In those cases:

There is an extension to CLLocationCoordinate2D in the [Euclid package](https://github.com/timsearle/Euclid) which performs the computation directly, see: [distance(to:)](https://github.com/timsearle/Euclid/blob/master/Sources/Euclid.swift#L159)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**: CLLocationCoordinate2D extension to calculate distance:

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    /// Returns distance from coordianate in meters.
    /// - Parameter from: coordinate which will be used as end point.
    /// - Returns: Returns distance in meters.
    func distance(from: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let from = CLLocation(latitude: from.latitude, longitude: from.longitude)
        let to = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
        return from.distance(from: to)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 11, longitude: 39)
let from = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30, longitude: 43)
let distance = coordinate.distance(from: from)
```

Answer (score -2):

`CLLocationDistance` is a measurement in meters.

```
let point1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat1, longitude: lon1)
let point2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat2, longitude: lon2)
let distance = point1.distance(to: point2)
```

Comment: There's no need to import another framework (MapKit) just for calculating distances. `CLLocation` *does* have a `distance(from:)` method that calculates distances between two `CLLocation` objects, and it's pure CoreLocation.

Comment: Swift 4+: Just use 
let distance = aLocation.distance(from: anotherLocation)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423689-distance