# Find the nearest location with my current location

Tags: ios, swift

Can you tell me what Google API can calculate distance for my current location with many places in my database?

For example, if I have many hospitals on my the map, how can I know the nearest place compared with my current location?

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: Look to the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432023/how-to-measure-the-distance-in-meters-between-two-cllocations

Comment: @Turnip it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: I am not getting why every one is down voting the question. Its a new question if he wants onroad distance between all points.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta It's being down voted because the question is off-topic and it shows no research effort.

Comment: @rmaddy k I understood there was no research effort, but what is off-topic. Please elaborate

Comment: @RahulDasgupta One of the off-topic close reasons: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: ok I got it , thanks

Comment: @MikeMertsock  it is not a duplicate question. It is asked in swift. can you answer him in swift.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get straight line distance then you can get it from

```
    loc1.distance(from: loc2)
```

But if you want to get on road distance then you can get it from google API.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626&key=AIzaSyDem7MBNNTTdrQsCN12s_OhjhPrxIqmpp4

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Here **key** is API Key that you have to generate, and **origins** is your origin latitude and longitude and **destinations** is series of destination.

You can easily click above api to see the results.